# What is the maximum number of $15 cm\times 15 cm$-square I can cut from a diameter $50 cm$- circle?

Tags: geometry, packing-problem

> What is the maximum number of $15 cm\times 15 cm$-square I can cut from a diameter $50 cm$- circle?(this square miss angle is ok, only such this  square area not than $\frac{1}{5}$ out the circle),see this following Figure(seven square all such condition)

First I think this answer is not than $10$,because
$$\dfrac{\pi\cdot 25^2}{15\cdot 15\cdot \frac{4}{5}}=10.9\cdots$$

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Erich's Packing Center](https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/index.html), the section on [squares in a circle](https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/squincir/), you will find that for a radius-to-edge-length ratio of $25/15=5/3=1.666\dots$ the maximal number of squares you can fit *completely* into the circle is $5$. At least that's the best known solution, as the site says: “Only the cases $n=1$ and $n=2$ have been proved optimal.”

If you allow up to $1/5$ of the area of each square to lie outside the circle, you could start with those configurations listed on that site. But there is no guarantee for optimality, since even the original configurations come with no such guarantee. You may want to search whether some of the solutions mentioned were published in some article, and whether that article describes methods which can be adapted to your situation. But my best bet is that everything essentially boils down to trial and error, and some good intuition.